# Не создается , и не заполняется таблица __EFMigrationsHistory

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Написал классы моделей, написал `DBContext`, попробовал сделать миграцию, вроде бы все получилось, однако, при выполнении миграции, или обновлении базы, происходит не понятное мне.

Используется MySQL как поставщик базы, и при выполнении миграции, не создается таблица:

```
Table 'mi_web_api.__efmigrationshistory' doesn't exist
```

Соответственно отпадает возможность делать откаты.

Что происходит не так?

Полный вывод при попытке сделтаь миграцию:

```
dotnet ef database update
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'ApiContext' using provider 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mi_web_api'
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (244ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `Genres` (
          `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` text NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (232ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `Studios` (
          `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` text NULL,
          `Logotype` text NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (275ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `Games` (
          `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` varchar(767) NULL,
          `Year` int NOT NULL,
          `StudioId` int NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
          CONSTRAINT `FK_Games_Studios_StudioId` FOREIGN KEY (`StudioId`) REFERENCES `Studios` (`Id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (343ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `GamesGenres` (
          `GameInfoId` int NOT NULL,
          `GenreInfoId` int NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`GameInfoId`, `GenreInfoId`),
          CONSTRAINT `FK_GamesGenres_Games_GameInfoId` FOREIGN KEY (`GameInfoId`) REFERENCES `Games` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `FK_GamesGenres_Genres_GenreInfoId` FOREIGN KEY (`GenreInfoId`) REFERENCES `Genres` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (233ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX `IX_Games_StudioId` ON `Games` (`StudioId`);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (115ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX `IX_Games_Id_Name` ON `Games` (`Id`, `Name`);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (207ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX `IX_GamesGenres_GenreInfoId` ON `GamesGenres` (`GenreInfoId`);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables
      WHERE table_name = '
      __EFMigrationsHistory' AND table_schema = DATABASE()
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables
      WHERE table_name = '
      __EFMigrationsHistory' AND table_schema = DATABASE()
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `MigrationId`, `ProductVersion`
      FROM `__EFMigrationsHistory`
      ORDER BY `MigrationId`;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'mi_web_api.__efmigrationshistory' doesn't exist
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `MigrationId`, `ProductVersion`
FROM `__EFMigrationsHistory`
ORDER BY `MigrationId`;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'mi_web_api.__efmigrationshistory' doesn't exist
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.GetAppliedMigrations()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Table 'mi_web_api.__efmigrationshistory' doesn't exist
```

Comment: вы пытаетесь накатить миграцию на уже сущетвующую БД или вы создали БД при помощи миграции?

Comment: Создаю при помощи миграций

Comment: тогда странно, в моем pet проекте всё сразу завелось, у меня asp.net core 2.2 + ef + mysql

Comment: А версия сервера влиять на это может?

Comment: навряд ли. Только я юзар другого провайдера, что то типа Pomelo или типа того.

Comment: Поставил `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`, таблица теперь есть, но записей в ней нет -_-

Comment: я как доберусь до дома, попробую отыскать мой код с миграциями. Он рабтал нормально, всё создавал, никаких проблем не случалось.

Comment: @tym32167, хм, а может ли вызывать проблему то, что при вызове `dotnet ef`, в консоли пишется о том что используется `.NET Core 3`, а в проекте `2.2.6`?

Comment: блин, забыл вчера про вас. Может быть и так, у меня 3 версия не установлена и всё работает как надо.

Comment: @tym32167, в общем, я нашел как решить проблему. Если делать миграцию через консоль пакетов нагет, и после этого обновлять базу, то все появляется, а если делать через командную строку в папке с проектом, то происходит то что я описал в вопросе. Однако все же не ясна истина этой проблемы.

Comment: хм, я делал только в консоли nuget, может потому не видел вашу проблему.